# Azure service bus with qpid JMS java client messages not taking from queue

Tags: message-queue, spring-jms, azureservicebus, qpid

I am using Azure service-bus queues (AMQP Protocol) with Apache Qpid (0.3) as Java client.
I am also using Spring JmsTemplate to produce messages and DefaultMessageListenerContainer to manage my consumers, spring JMS 4.0.6.

Spring configurations:

```
@PostConstruct
private void JndiLookup() throws NamingException {
    // Configure JNDI environment
    Hashtable<String, String> envPrp = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    envPrp.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory.class.getName());
    envPrp.put("connectionfactory.SBCF", "amqps://owner:{parimeryKey}@{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net");
    envPrp.put("queue.STORAGE_NEW_QUEUE", "QueueName");
    context = new InitialContext(envPrp);
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws NamingException {
    ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) context.lookup("SBCF");
    return cf;
}

@Bean
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() throws NamingException {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    messageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("QueueName");
    messageListenerContainer.setDestination(queue);
    messageListenerContainer.setConcurrency("3-10");
    MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter();
    adapter.setDelegate(new MessageWorker());
    adapter.setDefaultListenerMethod("onMessage");
    messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(adapter);
    return messageListenerContainer;
}

@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws NamingException {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

Nothing fancy in the configurations just straight forward.

Running the code and everything seems to be working .. but after few minutes without traffic in the queue it seems like the consumers are losing connection with the queue and not taking messages.

I dont know if it is related but every 5 minutes in am getting the following warning:

```
Fri Nov 07 15:23:53 +0000 2014, (DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:842) WARN : Setup of JMS   message listener invoker failed for destination   'org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.QueueImpl@8fb0427b' - trying to recover. Cause: Force detach the   link because the session is remotely ended. 
Fri Nov 07 15:23:56 +0000 2014, (DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:891) INFO : Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
```

I have messages being in the queue for hours and not being handled by the consumers only when I restart the app the consumers renewing the connection properly and taking the messages.

Is it possible that the problem is with the Spring Listener container properties or qpid connection factory or is it an issue with Azure service bus??

Couldn't find related post to my situation will appreciate the help!!

Comment: Hi! now facing the same issue. Has you found the way to fix it?

Comment: Session is remotely ended indicates azure service bus ending the session mostly due to inactivity. Can you check azure service bus settings?